# What is the best way to check whether a particular string is present in a hostname or not?

Tags: java, string, indexof

I have a hostname like this `p-desktop-1234565.teck.host.com` which I need to check whether it is in `teck` domain/datacenter or not. Any hostname will be in `teck` domain, if it has `.teck.` in the hostname.

As an example we might have machine in other datacenters `(dc1, dc2, dc3)` so there hostname will be like this -

```
machineA.dc1.host.com
machineB.dc2.host.com
machineC.dc3.host.com
```

In the same way might have some machine in `teck` domain so we might have hostname like this -

```
machineD.teck.host.com
```

So I need to check whether any machine is in `teck` datacenter or not. So I have got the below code which works fine -

```
String hostname = getHostName();

if (hostname != null) {
    if (isTeckHost(hostname)) {
        // do something
    }
}

// does this look right or is there any other better way?
private static boolean isTeckHost(String hostName) {
    return hostName.indexOf("." + TECK.name().toLowerCase() + ".") >= 0;
}
```

I wanted to check whether indexOf is the right way to use here? Or is there any better or efficient way to do the same thing?

Note: This piece of code is in my Enum class in which TECK is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String's contains() method if you just need to check if a string contains another string. For example:

```
if(hostName.toLowerCase().contains("." + TECK.name().toLowerCase() + "."))
```

Use String's split method if you need to check if a string is in a certain place in the hostname (e.g. before the first period, before the second period, etc.). For example:

```
if(hostName.toLowerCase().split("\\.")[1].equals(TECK.name().toLowerCase()))
```

split() returns a string array that contains the substrings in the string it is called on that are divided by a certain regex pattern, in this case, a full stop.

For example, when `split("\\.")` is called on the string `p-desktop-1234565.teck.host.com`, it will return the following array:
`{"p-desktop-1234565", "teck", "host", "com"}`. We then check (using `[1]`) if the second item in the array is equal to "teck".

Comment: what about if the hostname actually contains TECK? So this will return always true. I need to make sure it is `.TECH.` in the hostname.

Comment: `machineE.dc4.teck.com` would return true though.... even though it's not the tech datacenter.....

Comment: @DermotBlair you may also consider adding hostname.toLowerCass().contains() just to ensure you don't miss anything via capitalization.

Comment: I though any hostname that contained ".teck." was a teck data center?

Comment: What hostnames can contain ".teck." that are not teck data centers?

Comment: `machineE.dc4.teck.com` isn't a teck datacenter, its a teck host. `machineE.teck.teck.com` is a teck datacenter. If you look at the syntax of `machineC.dc3.host.com` it's clearly machine - datacenter - host - com

Answer (score 1):

While the contains method is generally safe to use, for a purpose such as this I recommend a combination of `split()` and `.equals()`

eg:

```
String[] x = hostname.split("\."); // this splits the string, and since the host is always in the second spot, you can do the following
if (x[1].equals(TECK.name().toLowerCase())) { 
    // do your stuff 
}
```

This one is safer in the sense that I can't break it with a string like
`machineE.dc4.teck.com` (assuming that this isn't allowed)